# $x_1,x_2...x_m$ are integers where $-2\leq x_j\leq1$, for all j=1,2,...m and $S_r=\sum_{j=1}^mx_j^r,S_1=22,S_4=184.$ Then $\max(S_3)-\min(S_3)$ is?

Tags: summation

> $x_1,x_2...x_m$ are integers where $-2\leq x_j\leq1$, for all j=1,2,...m and $S_r=\sum_{j=1}^mx_j^r,S_1=22,S_4=184.$ Then $\max(S_3)-\min(S_3)$ is?

My attempt:

$$
\begin{align*}
S_1&=x_1+x_2+x_3+\ldots =22\\
S_4&=x^4_1+x^4_2+x^4_3+\ldots=184
\end{align*}$$

$x_j$ can be $-2,-1,0,1$

I think $x_3$ can take multiple values because the answer is not zero, however this is not mentioned anywhere in the question. I don't know how to proceed further

Comment: It seems that you put subindices and superindices the other way around (only in "my attempt" part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we are not interested in all $i$ with $x_i=0$, because these $x_i$ do not effect any sum. Let $a$ be the number of $x_i$, that are 1, and let $b$ be the number of $x_i$, that are $-1$ and let $c$ be   the number of $x_i$, that are $-2$. We have

$$
\begin{align*}
22  &= a-b-2c\\
184 &= a+b+16c\end{align*}
$$
Adding both equations respectively substracting both equations yields

$$\begin{align*}
103 &=a+7c\\
81  &=b+9c
\end{align*}$$
Since $a,b,c\geq 0$, there are only $10$ choices for $c$ namely $0\leq c\leq 9$. You have to do the rest on your own.